# Linq grouping by item count from joined table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I had a look through a bunch of answers, and tried to get the code working but couldn't see a way to group by the _productBundlesItemsRepository table

Here is the query I'm looking at

```
return _productBundlesRepository.Table.Join(_productBundleItemsRepository.Table,
                    pbr => pbr.Id,
                    pbir => pbir.BundleId,
                    (pbr, pbir) => new { Bundle = pbr, BundleItem = pbir})
                .Where(x => x.BundleItem.ProductId == productId && x.BundleItem.Visible == true && x.Bundle.Active == true).Select(x => x.Bundle).ToList();
```

I thought maybe I could do something like this
`.OrderByDescending(x => x.BundleItem.Count())` but that option is not available

I also tried something like grabbing the count of items linked to the bundle in the new statement like this

```
new { Bundle = pbr, BundleItem = pbir, Count = GetProductBundleItems(pbr.Id).Count})
```

But then I get an error like this

> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Not really sure how I go about ordering the bundles returned by the number of bundle items contained within the bundle.

UPDATE I used some modified code based on the answer from @StriplingWarrior but it appears this will not work, as multiple bundles can contain the same item.
ie one bundle is a 2 pack, and another bundle is a 4 pack both use the same item.
Here is my updated code

```
var bundleItems = _productBundleItemsRepository.Table
                .Where(bundleItem => bundleItem.ProductId == productId
                                     && bundleItem.Visible == true);
            return _productBundlesRepository.Table
                .Select(bundle => new BundleWithCount { pb = bundle, count = bundleItems.Count(bundleItem => bundleItem.BundleId == bundle.Id) })
                .Where(x => x.pb.Active == true && x.count > 0).OrderByDescending(x => x.count).Select(x => x.pb)
                .ToList();
```

with

```
internal class BundleWithCount
    {
        public int count { get; set; }

        public ProductBundle pb { get; set; }
    }
```

Anyone see where I might be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple bundles can contain the same item"?  If a BundleItem has a single BundleId, doesn't that mean the relationship is many-to-one? Even if not, you'll need to clarify what "will not work" about this? Are you getting an error? Results different from what you expect? Need more details.

Comment: I figured it out @StriplingWarrior Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work this out, with the number of items ordered first then the item quantity. Just how I planned to do it. Thanks @StriplingWarrior for pointing me in the right direction :)

```
public List<ProductBundle> GetBundlesActive()
        {
            var bundleItems = _productBundleItemsRepository.Table
                .Where(bundleItem => bundleItem.Visible == true);
            var bundleItemCount = _productBundleItemsRepository.Table
                .Where(bundleItem => bundleItem.Visible == true);
            return _productBundlesRepository.Table
                .Select(bundle => new BundleWithCount { Pb = bundle, Count = bundleItems.Count(bundleItem => bundleItem.BundleId == bundle.Id), ItemCount = bundleItemCount.FirstOrDefault(bundleItem => bundleItem.BundleId == bundle.Id).Quantity })
                .Where(x => x.Pb.Active == true && x.Count > 0).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).ThenByDescending(x => x.ItemCount).Select(x => x.Pb)
                .ToList();
        }
```

and internal class of this

```
internal class BundleWithCount
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }

        public int ItemCount { get; set; }

        public ProductBundle Pb { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A Join isn't really great when you're not wanting get the scalar data from both tables. Something like this would be more effective for just getting the Bundles.

```
return _productBundlesRepository.Table
    .Where(bundle => bundle.Active == true
        && _productBundleItemsRepository.Table
            .Any(bundleItem => bundleItem.BundleId == bundle.Id
                 && bundleItem.ProductId == productId 
                 && bundleItem.Visible == true))
    .ToList();
```

Or, put another way:

```
var bundleItems = _productBundleItemsRepository.Table
    .Where(bundleItem => bundleItem.ProductId == productId 
        && bundleItem.Visible == true);
return _productBundlesRepository.Table
    .Where(bundle => bundle.Active == true
        && bundleItems.Any(bundleItem => bundleItem.BundleId == bundle.Id))
    .ToList();
```

Then, if you want the count of bundle items per bundle:

```
var bundleItems = _productBundleItemsRepository.Table
    .Where(bundleItem => bundleItem.ProductId == productId 
        && bundleItem.Visible == true);
return _productBundlesRepository.Table
    .Select(bundle => new BundleWithCount {bundle, count=bundleItems.Count(bundleItem => bundleItem.BundleId == bundle.Id)})
    .Where(x => x.bundle.Active == true && x.count > 0)
    .ToList();
```

(You'll need to define the `BundleWithCount` class so you can return a generic based on objects of that type)

Comment: Hey Thansk for the help, this ```new BundleWithCount { bundle``` bundle says "invalid initializer member declarator"

Comment: Hi StriplingWarrior I got the code working but have an issue, please see my update in the question.
Thanks